# Can't post cURL from php to nodejs

Tags: php, node.js, curl

This function stopped working after I changed some of my algorithms, I might have messed up. Here is my code:

```
$data = (
    [field1] => some_message
    [field2] => some_message
    [field3] => Array
        (
            [more] => information
        )

)

function curlRequest($url,$querystring,$encoded_json = false){

    $ch = curl_init();

    $ch_options = array("Expect:");

    if($encoded_json)
        array_push($ch_options,"Content-type: application/json");

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $ch_options);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $querystring);

    curl_getinfo($ch);

    curl_exec($ch);

    $feedback = curl_getinfo($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $feedback;

}

function notifyNode($data,$encoded_json = false) {

    $node_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:'.$socket_port.'/posts';

    if(is_string($data))
        $data = array($data);

    $querystring = http_build_query($data);

    //querystring seems fine

    $feedback = curlRequest($node_url,$querystring,$encoded_json);

}
```

if `$data` is sent in `notifyNode`:

`$querystring` seems fine
`curl_getinfo($ch);` (right before `exec`) dumps this:

```
var_dump: 
array(26) {
  ["url"]=>
  string(27) "http://127.0.0.1:port/posts" (this is correct)
  ["content_type"]=>
  NULL
  ["http_code"]=>
  int(0)
  ["header_size"]=>
  int(0)
  ["request_size"]=>
  int(0)
  ["filetime"]=>
  int(0)
  ["ssl_verify_result"]=>
  int(0)
  ["redirect_count"]=>
  int(0)
  ["total_time"]=>
  float(0)
  ["namelookup_time"]=>
  float(0)
  ["connect_time"]=>
  float(0)
  ["pretransfer_time"]=>
  float(0)
  ["size_upload"]=>
  float(0)
  ["size_download"]=>
  float(0)
  ["speed_download"]=>
  float(0)
  ["speed_upload"]=>
  float(0)
  ["download_content_length"]=>
  float(-1)
  ["upload_content_length"]=>
  float(-1)
  ["starttransfer_time"]=>
  float(0)
  ["redirect_time"]=>
  float(0)
  ["redirect_url"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["primary_ip"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["certinfo"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["primary_port"]=>
  int(0)
  ["local_ip"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["local_port"]=>
  int(0)
}
```

**I want the data to be received in json format via nodejs side so I really don't understand what is happening**. Tyvm for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make some corrections in your curl options:
Instead of:

```
$ch_options = array("Expect:");

if($encoded_json)
    array_push($ch_options,"Content-type: application/json");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $ch_options);
```

use

```
$ch_options = array("Expect:");

if($encoded_json){
   array_push($ch_options,"Content-Type: application/json");
}  

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $ch_options);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
...
```

If you want to send data from PHP to NodeJS in json format then pass in `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` option json_encoded data:

```
...
$querystring = jsone_encode($data);
...
```

Comment: So if I want to pass `json` I don't http_query_string the data? Are you sure about this?

Comment: do you want to send json or receive json as response from nodejs?